# $F(x,y)$ continues at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

We have $F(x,y)=f(x), f(x)$ continues at $x_0$.

How to prove that: for every $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $F(x,y)$ continues at $(x_0, y_0)$?

Comment: This is a simple consequence of the definition of continuous functions: You need to show that the limit of $F(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(x_0, y_0)$ is $F(x_0, y_0)$. As $(x,y)$ approaches $(x_0, y_0)$, particularly $x$ approaches $x_0$, and you may use that then $f(x)$ approaches $f(x_0)$. Are you having trouble with writing a formal solution?

Comment: Yeah! Could you write a formal solution?

Answer (score 1):

Continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ : $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \alpha > 0,\forall x \in\mathbb{R}, |x-x_0| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$

Continuity of $F$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ : $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \alpha > 0,\forall (x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2, \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$

> Take $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$
>
> Take some $\varepsilon>0$
>
> Continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ gives you $\alpha$ so that $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}, |x-x_0| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$
>
> $\forall (x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2, F(x,y)=f(x)$
>
> So $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,|x-x_0|<\alpha \Rightarrow |F(x,y)-F(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$
>
> On $\mathbb{R}^2$, all the norms are equivalent so you can just prove it for a given norm. I'll chose $\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|=\max\{|x-a|,|y-b|\}$
>
> With this norm, $|x-x_0|\le\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|$ so $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\alpha \Rightarrow |x-x_0|<\alpha$
>
> Which gives you $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\alpha \Rightarrow |x-x_0|<\alpha \Rightarrow |F(x,y)-F(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$
>
> By transitivity of $\Rightarrow$, $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|<\alpha\Rightarrow |F(x,y)-F(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$
>
> You took an unspecified $\varepsilon$ and found an $\alpha$ satisfying the property so
>
> $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \alpha > 0,\forall (x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2, \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$
>
> i.e. $F$ is continous at $x$
>
> Since you also took an unspecified $y_0$,
>
> $\forall y_0\in\mathbb{R},\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \alpha > 0,\forall (x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2, \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\| < \alpha \Rightarrow |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: The blockquote was supposed to be a `>!` thing that would be hidden but if I replace `>` by `>!`, it removes all the newline characters...